# Set the digits in a float after decimal point

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to write a c++ function which converts a float to const char *. Here in this function, an argument is passed to specify the decimal places that output value should represent. I have come up this functions and it works nicely.

I would like to whether, there are any better ways write this function?.

```
static const char* getString(float value, int decimalPlaces)
{
     char strValue[sizeof value];
     sprintf(strValue, "%.%df", value, decimalPlaces);
     return strValue;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof value` is the number of bytes used to represent a `float`, which may not be enough for your `sprintf`.  You return a pointer to a local array, whose lifetime ends before you can use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two major problems with your function.

To begin with the size of `float` is on most platform four bytes, which means your array is only four elements. Not enough for all the digits of your floating point value. Writing out of bounds will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The second problem is that you return a pointer to a local variable. The array `strValue` will go out of scope once the function returns, and the pointer will now be a so-called *stray pointer*. Dereferencing it will also lead to undefined behavior.

In short, your function does *not* "work nicely". It doesn't really work at all.

The obvious solution is to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert the floating point value to a string. Then when you need a C-style null-terminated string (for whatever reason) you use the strings [`c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) member function to get such a pointer.

If you need a specific number of decimals, use an [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and standard [I/O manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) to format the string the way you want. If your goal is to get a string to output you can of course skip this step, and use the manipulators directly when writing the output.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Here what I want is to return a const char*. Using c_str(), we can achieve it. So if we use this approach don't you think that there are unnecessary steps like first converting to std::string and then to a const char*.

Answer (score 2):

When you `return strValue;` you are going to return a pointer to a local variable.  That means when the function ends that variable goes away and now you have a pointer to nothing.  Using that pointer is undefined behavior.

You are either going to have to use `new[]` to allocate the buffer and then you need to remember to `delete[]`the pointer in the call site or use something like a `std::string` and let the string itself handle the memory management.

Personally I would use a `std::string` and a `std::stringstream` like:

```
static std::string getMString(float value, int decimalPlaces)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(decimalPlaces) << value;
    return stream.str();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Here what I want is to return a const char*. Using c_str(), we can achieve it. So if we use this approach don't you think that there are unnecessary steps like first converting to std::string and then to a const char*.

Comment: @TharinduKumara If you want to return a pointer you need `new[]` and `delete[]`.  Personally I would return the string and then if you need the `const char*` then you can us the `c_str()` method of the returned string in the call site.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with your function, since `char strValue[]` is deleted once you leave `getMString` and you return pointer to deleted data, this is UB.

I suggest not to invent anything, but use C++11 `std::to_string(float)`

Comment: The array is not **deleted** (there is no call to `delete`). It simply goes away.

Comment: That is why they say about end of life of local object. It is implementation defined, what and when something would happen to data in that memory